# How to get the message link of messages the bot has sent?

Tags: python, discord

So I've seen some bots in the past that will send a dm to you and in the channel where you ran the command it will have a discord message link that puts you on the message that the bot sent to you in dms. Here is what I got

```
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.author.send("hi")
  await ctx.send(f"Heres the link to the message! {link}")
```

( ignore the indenting )
so what I want is for the bot to get the link of the message it sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign message to variable

```
msg = await ctx.author.send("hi")
```

and get its link

```
link = msg.jump_url
```

Comment: Thanks a lot do you know how I would put that into a word so like you click a word in a embed or message it will send you to the dms?

Comment: you can use markdown `[text](link)` but only in embed.